# Why is my Catalyst application slow to restart?

Tags: perl, catalyst

Each time I build a Catalyst application I come to a point where the application gets painfully slow to (re)start, the delay is about 10 seconds. Today I figured the delay is caused by the following lines:

```
use lib '/home/zoul/opt/lib/perl/5.8';
use lib '/home/zoul/opt/share/perl/5.8';
use lib '/home/zoul/opt/lib/perl/5.8.8';
use lib '/home/zoul/opt/share/perl/5.8.8';
```

These lines are only needed on the server, since I haven’t got root access there and have my Perl modules installed under `~/opt`. (I can’t use Apache’s `SetEnv` module, since the hoster does not support it. Therefore I have to enter the library paths into `App.pm`.) On my development machine that exhibits the gory delay the paths do not exist.

My questions: (1) Why do the lines cause so much delay, about 7 seconds? (2) What’s a nice way to solve this? Naive conditional `use` does not work:

```
if ($on_the_hosting_machine)
{
    use lib '…';
}
```

I guess I could `eval` somehow, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not do `Catalyst`, so I am not sure if this is going solve your problem, but you can try to do what is essentially what `lib.pm` does:

```
BEGIN { 
    if ( $on_the_hosting_machine ) {
        unshift @INC, qw'
            /home/zoul/opt/lib/perl/5.8
            /home/zoul/opt/share/perl/5.8
            /home/zoul/opt/lib/perl/5.8.8
            /home/zoul/opt/share/perl/5.8.8
        ';
    }
};
```

Comment: You can also set libraries with the PERL5LIB environment variable.

Comment: Yes, but I don’t think I have access to the environment before the application starts. (That’s what I have been writing about Apache’s SetEnv, which would have permitted me to set the environment beforehand.)

Answer (score 6):

1) Every time you have a use or require statement, it searches through all the directories in lib in order.  Each use lib does (at least) two stat calls.

use lib is just a wrapper for pushing things onto @LIB... but it also searches for the presence of an arch directory and pushes that on to @LIB if it exists, too.

You can reverse the change using the no lib pragma:

```
no lib ('/home/zoul/opt/lib/perl/5.8', '/home/zoul/opt/share/perl/5.8', '/home/zoul/opt/lib/perl/5.8.8', '/home/zoul/opt/share/perl/5.8.8');
```

Better yet, you could modify your dev environment to match production, or even just symlink those directories to the real locations for your dev setup.

Answer (score 5):

Check out ["A Timely Start"](http://www.perl.com/pub/2005/12/21/a_timely_start.html) by Jean-Louis Leroy on [Perl.com](http://www.perl.com). He describes the same problem and a clever fix for it.

Comment: The link to that article does not work since Perl.com was taken over by the community. Now it is available as http://www.perl.com/pub/2005/12/21/a_timely_start.html (worth reading).